# In Angular 10 promise is not executing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise

In my project I'm using Angular 10, I have to call one API request async way. So I tried with promises. but while executing the code it's not called the API. It always exists with the first line itself. I wasn't able to find the reason for this. It's not going for resolved or rejected.

This is my ts.code:

```
public setUser(): () => Promise<any> {
return (): Promise<any> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //get user details
    this.api.get<any>(environment.apiUserRoot + `/Users/current`).subscribe(
      userData => {
        this.storage.clearIdentity();
        this.assignLoginUserToUser(userData.body);
      },
      err => {
        this.storage.clearIdentity();
      }
    );
  });
};
}

 private assignLoginUserToUser(user: UserModel): void {
    this.loginUser = user;
 }
 

public getUserContext(): UserModel {
   this.setUser();
   return this.loginUser;
}
```

Comment: You need to call `resolve` to resolve the promise. Looking at your code, you probably don't need to use a promise with an observable; Unlike an observable, once a promise is resolved, it's done, it won't change its state again.

Comment: Also we can't see where (if anywhere) you call the function this method returns and it's unclear why you're using new Promise at all rather than the first/lastValueFrom RxJS functions (or .toPromise method, if you're still on an older version as Angular 10 suggests).

Comment: @Yousaf Thanks for your comments, but that is not resolving..

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit too complex, I would rather simplify it by doing something like this:

```
public setUser(): void {
  this.api.get<any>(environment.apiUserRoot + `/Users/current`).subscribe({
    next: (userData) => {
      this.storage.clearIdentity();
      this.assignLoginUserToUser(userData.body);
    },
    error: (err) => {
      this.storage.clearIdentity();
    },
  });
}
```

It is not clear from the usage if you actually need a return value, but if you do, then you have a few options depending on the rxjs version that you use:

- If you don't have [`firstValueFrom`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom):

```
public setUser(): Promise<any> {
  return this.api.get<any>(environment.apiUserRoot + `/Users/current`)
  .toPromise().then(userData => {
    this.storage.clearIdentity();
    this.assignLoginUserToUser(userData.body);
    return userData;
  }).catch(() => {
    this.storage.clearIdentity();
  });
}
```

- If you have `firstValueFrom` then you could do it like this:

```
public setUser(): Promise<any> {
  return firstValueFrom(this.api.get<any>(environment.apiUserRoot + `/Users/current`))
  .then(userData => {
    this.storage.clearIdentity();
    this.assignLoginUserToUser(userData.body);
    return userData;
  }).catch(() => {
    this.storage.clearIdentity();
  });
}
```

For getting the user, you have a couple of options depending on your async implementation choice (observable or promise; I personally recommend observables):

- With observables, the `setUser` should not perform the subscribe itself, and do the things it needs to do as a side effect using `tap` and return the observable to be used later by the calling code.

```
public setUser(): Observable<UserModel> {
  return this.api.get<any>(environment.apiUserRoot + `/Users/current`).pipe(
    tap(result => {
      this.storage.clearIdentity();
      this.assignLoginUserToUser(result.body);
      return result.body;
    }),
    catchError(err => {
      this.storage.clearIdentity();
      return of(null);
    })
  );
}
```

The `getUserContext` should not be synchronous anymore, but return an Observable instead:

```
public getUserContext(): Observable<UserModel> {
   return this.setUser();
}
```

This implies that you need to adjust the calling code to subscribe to this observable returned by the `getUserContext` method like this:

```
getUserContext().subscribe(user => {
  // do something with the user here.
});
```

- With promises, you need to return the promise that you obtained from the `setUser` method using any of the implementations above (with `.toPromise` or `firstValueFrom`)

```
public getUserContext(): Promise<UserModel> {
   return this.setUser().then(result => result.body);
}
```

The calling code in this case also needs some adjustments, in order to accommodate the fact that `getUserContext` is not synchronous anymore:

```
const user = await getUserContext();
```

or using `then`

```
getUserContext().then(user => {
  // do something with the user here.
});
```

Comment: Hi Octavian it's working as expected but for the first time its not executing the get method, second time only its executing. any ways to fix this?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what _get method_ is supposed to do? Maybe even include it in the body of your question to have a better look at it.

Comment: Actually in get method i have to fetch user information then pass to the other component, based on the user data using directive i have to change the content in UI. but for the first time its not executing the get method, so because of that it send the user data as undefined and UI also breaking.

Comment: octavian i added in the question itself.

Comment: `getUserContext` is a synchronous method, which means it won't wait for the `this.loginUser` to be assigned before it returns. Can you make this method async (either by returning a promise, or an observable)?

Comment: Can you give me some examples how we can go with this way?

Comment: I edited the answer to better reflect the choices you have.

Comment: Thank you Octavian for your clear explanation with codes.